# Calling a blur function when the page loads

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jQuery delegate which calculates the sum of textboxes when the user adds a number

So the totals work when the user tabs out.

The issue I am having is when the page loads and if there are already existing values the user has to click the text box and tab out for the totals to work.

The code I have is:

```
$body.delegate("input.actionvalue", "blur", function (e) {
}
```

I am not sure how to call this function when the page loads.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Would you be able to add more code to make your question more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put what you have inside `$body.delegate("input.actionvalue", "blur", function (e) { }` in a function called e.g. `checkValues()` like so:

```
function checkValues() {
    //whatever
}

$body.delegate("input.actionvalue", "blur", function (e) {
    checkValues(); //this one is called onBlur
});

//this one is called when the page loads
checkValues();
```

Comment: why not just $body.delegate("input.actionvalue", "blur", checkValues);

Answer (score 0):

If you seperate your event handler you can call it when the page loads easily.

```
    // Wait until the DOM has loaded (also keeps your variables safe from occupying the global namespace
    $(function() {

        function eventHandler(e) {
            // The e or 'event' object will only be passed by the .on() method, so referencing it when you call the function normally will throw an error. Should you need to use the event object you can check for it first
            e && e.preventDefault();
        }

        // Using the newer .on() method for events (delegate is deprecated in newer versions of jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/on/
        $body.on("blur", "input.actionvalue", eventHandler);

        // Run your handler once when the page loads
        eventHandler();

    });
```

Comment: hello Simon,Can you explain this further?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741505/pass-e-parameter-jquery . I am having a $this just like in this example and it is looking for a variable. That was the reason it was failing when I tried to use on page load

Comment: Hello Simon, Can you still help me on this?

Comment: Hey, just looked at the your question and your accepted answer seems to provide the solution I would suggest. Does that not work as you expected?

Comment: var $this = $(this);
    var penText = $this.attr("inputPEN");
    var subbpenText = $this.attr("inputSubBPEN");

   var idText = $this.attr("inputIndex");
    var installText = $this.attr("inputInstall");
    installText = remove(installText, " ");
    installationText = remove(installationText, "/");
    $this.val(formatCurrency($this.val()));

Comment: $body.delegate("input.actionvalue", "blur", checkvalues);

Comment: I think this is getting outside the scope of comments. If the question you linked to was not the answer you expected, perhaps you should post a new one. I can certainly take a look as well :)